# RegEx validation Error javascript for Numeric Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate Integer and float value in javascript but failed to achieve it. It always allow "." .  Please help me to solve this regex error.

result :- 1,1.1,.1

I am checking in onkeypress event. It is not working in that.

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress="Test()" style="width:100px"/>

   function Test() {

        var code;
        var character;
        if (document.all)
        {
            code = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else {
            code = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].which;
        }
        var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
        var txt = new RegExp('([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+');//only numueric value

        if (!txt.test(character)) {
            if (document.all) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            }
            else {
                arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you mean that you want to allow whole numbers only, remove `[.]` from your Regex

Comment: Do you want to test only integer or also float?

Comment: @Toto i need to test integer + float

Comment: Please consider adding some examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: [Please use the search feature](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+validate+number+regex)

Comment: @nichu09: Your regex should work.

Comment: @Toto i tried it. but not working. it is not allow " . "

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really appreciate your comment. i tried before. but i don't get the proper result. so i posted it.

Comment: The point is that you check each character one by one, after they are input, right? The regex `([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits optionally preceded with 0+ digits and a `.`. So, the regex only matches a *digit*. To match a digit *or* dot, use `[0-9.]` regex. Bascially, you do not need a regex at all, you could just check char codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1) Use "onkeyup" instead of "onkeypress"

2) Use this RegExp:

```
(^(- )?[0-9]*([\.]?[0-9]+)?$)
```

I placed it in an online tester and you can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/zL1mB0/3

*Updated Answer Version since your first Question Edit*

Comment: please check my updated question. your answer also not working in that condition.

Comment: I updated it so it works for the "result :- 1,1.1,.1". Check it again

Comment: If it's not good, please make an effort to explain exactly what should work and what shouldn't.